# Crystal Reports: How do I read a datetime parameter from SQL?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a formula field that basically does the following:

```
If {Date Field} = "1753-01-01 00:00:00.000" Then
""
Else
{Date Field}
```

I keep getting the error that I need to use an actual date-time formula. It's really annoying and I don't know what to do! I have tried certain nests to use around the date but they don't seem to work. Hoping one of you know a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date literals can be defined using the #date# notation. Then your else statement needs to be converted to text.

```
If {Date Field} = #1753-01-01# Then
""
Else
ToText({Date Field})
```

Comment: Wow..is it really that easy? Way to go.